# How to unit test a component's query evaluation in purescript-halogen?

Tags: unit-testing, purescript, halogen

A purescript-halogen component has an `eval` function defining how it evaluates queries. I'd like to write tests to cover the behaviour of the component; how would I go about doing this?

For instance, if my component has `GetValue` in its query algebra, I'd like to write a test which creates the component with initial state, evaluates a `GetValue` query, and asserts that the value received matches what was provided in the initial state. If my component also has a `SetValue`, I might like to assert that evaluating a `GetValue` after a `SetValue` returns what I expect.

I can't find any examples of this sort of testing (I refer to Slamdata's code a lot but the only tests I see there are Selenium tests).

I feel like the solution must lie in [Halogen.Component](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-halogen/0.11.0/docs/Halogen.Component), where functions like `queryComponent` and `initializeComponent` reside; I've looked at the [Halogen.Driver](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/master/src/Halogen/Driver.purs) source to try to understand how to use them but I've been unable to figure it out.

Could someone either point me to an example of testing a Halogen component, or explain how one would be able to create a component, have it evaluate a query, and observe the results?

Comment: This is a bit of an open question really. Halogen was designed with being able to do this sort of thing in mind, but we've not put anything into practice yet - the idea was to use a `g` for the component that allows for easy mocking of effectful actions (so `Aff` is unnecessary) and then using a custom driver to run the component... *waves hands* something. ;)